# Turbolinks 5 and setInterval issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, setinterval, turbolinks, turbolinks-5

I'm using [Turbolinks 5](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks) with [Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails) and I'm setting a JS interval in order to refresh page content each 10 seconds through AJAX:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    function fetchContent() {
      // some AJAX request
    }

    setInterval(fetchContent, 10000);
  });
</script>
```

When I first load the page containing the above code, it works: the `fetchContent` is fired every 10 seconds.

However, when I navigate to another page, the `fetchContent` keeps firing. Moreover, when I go back to the page (using the browser back button), the `fetchContent` fires unpredictably multiple times. Obviously, this is not the wanted behaviour.

How to fix this?

---

*Note*: To fix this, I know I could need a `clearInterval` call of some sort, but how should I make it using Turbolinks 5 e.g. what event should I bind? Since Turbolinks 5, [API has changed](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks/wiki/Turbolinks-5-FAQ#should-i-use-turbolinks-5-or-turbolinks-classic). In particular, all of the Turbolinks Classic events have been renamed, and several—including `page:update`—have been removed, so I cannot use solutions like [this](https://product.reverb.com/fun-with-setinterval-and-turbolinks-66f5fcb1bbcd), [this](https://gist.github.com/dv/fc51f798d825bff5a371) or [this](https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks-classic/issues/373).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Maybe* I found a solution. In `application.js` I stated:

```
function setIntervalWithTurbolinks(intervalFunction, milliseconds) {
  var interval = setInterval(intervalFunction, milliseconds);

  $(document).on('turbolinks:before-cache turbolinks:before-render', function() {
    clearTimeout(interval);
  });
}
```

So, in my application, I use it this way:

```
setIntervalWithTurbolinks(fetchContent, 10000);
```

Comment: Use `one` to invoke it once - otherwise you'll continuously be calling clearTimeout for an invalid id, potentially cancelling another interval accidentally from another piece of code